# Why are my Backbone Models nested strangely within a Collection, requiring drilling down to access methods/properties?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've got a Collection and a Model, both using attributes/options to augment them with additional capabilities. Here's the Model (**LoadRouteGroup**):

```
return Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log(this);
    },
    fetchf: function () {
        console.log("FETCH");
    }
});
```

And the Collection (**LoadRouteGroups**):

```
return Backbone.Collection.extend({
    constructUrl: function(options) {
        if (options.groupingType === "facility") {
            // TODO: new endpoint: /api/v1/loadroutes?grouping=facility
            this.url = clawConfig.endpoints.webApiRootUrl + "/api/loads/facilities";
        }
        else {
            this.url = clawConfig.endpoints.webApiRootUrl + "/api/v1/loadroutes";
        }
    },
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        options || (options = {});

        this.constructUrl(options);

        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

They're instantiated as such:

```
var loadRouteGroup = new LoadRouteGroup({
    entityType: "facility"
});

// WORKS
loadRouteGroup.fetchf();

// assign groupingType option to collection to denote which URL to use
var loadRouteGroups = new LoadRouteGroups({
    model: loadRouteGroup
}, {
    groupingType: "facility"
});

var firstGroup = loadRouteGroups.at(0);

// DOESN'T WORK
firstGroup.fetchf();

// WORKS
firstGroup.attributes.model.fetchf();
```

I would expect that call to `firstGroup.fetchf()` to work... but it doesn't. Instead, I have to weirdly drill down and use `firstGroup.attributes.model.fetchf()` in order to access the method.

What's going on here? This would seem straightforward to me, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with the relationship between my Collection and Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection definition should include the model type:

```
return Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // ....
    model: LoadRouteGroup
});
```

When initializing the collection, pass in an array of models:

```
var loadRouteGroup = new LoadRouteGroup({
    entityType: "facility"
});
var loadRouteGroups = new LoadRouteGroups([loadRouteGroup], {
    groupingType: "facility"
});
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do both things (define the collection's model and pass in the entity/grouping type) during initialization?

Comment: You should be specifying the model type when you define the class, not initialize the collection. Each collection in Backbone should correspond to only one model type, so it is specified when the collection is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the model when you extend the collection instead of when you instantiate.

Comment: Asked Lukas the same question, but: shouldn't I be able to do it either way?